# XmlSerializer.Deserialize() from Socket c#

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization

Here is a piece of code from my application:

```
using (NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(newClientSock))
{
   XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
   xs.Serialize(ns, _publicKey);

   RSAParameters clientPubKey = (RSAParameters)xs.Deserialize(ns);
}
```

What im trying to do is a form of "Handshake" between two client sockets. Im not very familiar with serialization, so my question is, will the XmlSerializer(xs) object wait for something to  be sent and then desirialize it, or the data that need to be desirialized should already be in that stream?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XmlSerializer will read the stream as it arrives at your end of the socket (i.e. will wait). There is no need to buffer it. However a common error is not to Flush the output stream at the sender end (making the deserializer at the other end wait forever). You should make sure you Flush it after you call Serialize().

Comment: Thanks for answering that fast, although i knew that it should wait, i could not find any answer online! :)